# find control and html tags

Tags: asp.net

i have this code in my default aspx file :

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="holder1" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="Label">
            </asp:Label>
            <input type="text" ID="txt" runat="server"/>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:Button Text="Ok" ID="btnOk" runat="server" onclick="btnOk_Click" />
        </asp:PlaceHolder>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and my code behind is :

```
        TextBox tb1 = holder1.FindControl("txt") as TextBox;
        Response.Write(tb1.Text);
        TextBox tb2 = holder1.FindControl("txt2") as TextBox;
        Response.Write(tb2.Text);
```

my problem is here that findcontrol ("txt") return null value!!! because i used `<input>` ,how can i handle this control ?

Comment: this condition happen if text box created with JS !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need the `holder1.FindControl` as you can access the controls directly.

To get the `input` control, use the code;

```
HtmlInputText tb1 = this.txt;
Response.Write(tb1.Value);
```

You might need to import System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.

```
Using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

**Edit**

To find controls which have been dynamically added via Javascript, you will need to use the `Request` object.

```
string theValue = Request.Form["txt"].ToString();
```

Comment: and what happen if my control <input> is not exist in the webform and it will generate dynamically when page is loaded , there is not liseted in `this.`!!!

Comment: If your `<input>` is added dynamically via javascript then it will never be found via `FindControl` as this only works with controls which have been rendered before PageLoad. To find these controls, you will need to look at the `Request.Form` object as these values will be posted to the page. e.g. `string theVal = Request.Form["txt"].ToString();`

Comment: Good , thx in advance . but for using `Request.Form["txt"]` i used name of my inputbox , `id` not work  because of post method of page

Answer (score 1):

An `input type="text"` is not a `TextBox`. So you either should cast it to [`HtmlInputText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext.aspx) or use a `TextBox` instead.

```
var txt = (HtmlInputText)row.FindControl("txt");
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls`,

Answer (score 0):

MSDN :

> **Control.FindControl** : Method Searches the current naming container for
>   the specified server control.

as  is not server control it is not pissible to find it ! any Other Way to handle controls that are not server side ?

what happen if any one want to get text of text box that is not run at server .