# FindControl CodeBehind Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, findcontrol

I have the following code in my aspx file:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="test" name="test" onBlur="OnBlurFunction()"/>
```

When I click a submit button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="SubmitButton" OnClick="SubmitButton" Text="Submit" />
```

The function "SubmitButton" contains the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.FindControl("test"));
```

When I run this, it always prints out a blank value and I'm not sure why. If I set the value in the HTML line as follows:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="test" name="test" value="hello" onBlur="OnBlurFunction()"/>
```

It prints "hello" with no issues. But when I manually change the value in the text box to something else, it always to print the first value out. It's as if something isn't dynamic. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: the best thing to do is to FindControl and convert it into the right type i.e TextBox. Then use the Text property to grab its value. For instance: var txtCtrl = this.FindControl("test") as TextBox; if (txtCtrl != null) { Debug.WriteLine(txtCtrl.Text); }

Comment: or use an asp:TextBox

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```
HtmlInputText tb1 = this.test;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tb1.Value);
```

This is the thread - [find control and html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566116/find-control-and-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You must use parent control(like asp:panel or runat server div) instead of this to call FindControl method.
Like this:

```
pnl1.FindControl("test")
```